# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.spark_project.protobuf.GeneratedMessage

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

When i try to run the spark application, i am getting the following exception.
I am using eclipse maven project. Please anyone suggest why this exception occurs.
Is there any dependency missing in pom.xml or there can be any other issue?
It is showing no error in the code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.spark_project.protobuf.GeneratedMessage
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:21)
        at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:20)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
        at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(ReflectiveDynamicAccess.scala:20)
        at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$6.apply(Serialization.scala:265)
        at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$6.apply(Serialization.scala:264)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:728)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:221)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:428)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:727)
        at akka.serialization.Serialization.<init>(Serialization.scala:264)
        at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.createExtension(SerializationExtension.scala:15)
        at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.createExtension(SerializationExtension.scala:12)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.registerExtension(ActorSystem.scala:745)
        at akka.actor.ExtensionId$class.apply(Extension.scala:79)
        at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.apply(SerializationExtension.scala:12)
        at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:175)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:656)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:653)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:653)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:669)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1832)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1823)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:270)
        at org.test.scala.test1.main(test1.java:13)
```

My code is like:-

```
package org.test.scala;

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;



public class test1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //  SparkConf sparkConf = new   SparkConf().setAppName("JavaSparkSQL").setMaster("local");
      SparkContext sc=new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("sql").setMaster("local"));
      SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
        DataFrame lines = sqlContext.jsonFile("sample.json");
         System.out.println(lines.toString());
        lines.registerTempTable("lines");
  }
}
```

please give some suggestion.
Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.test1</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark3</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>spark3</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spark-project.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1-shaded</version>
</dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-alpha1</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>  
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing or have conflicting libraries.  Show us your maven or other library configs.

Also GeneratedMessage is a protobuf class which tends to be built upon compilation.  Have you tried running "Generate Sources and Update Folders"?

Comment: In our project I can see your missing class is located in the following library.  Keep in mind ours is not a spark project:
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                <version>${protobuf.version}</version>
            </dependency>

<protobuf.version>2.6.1</protobuf.version>